# Adding list of data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following code works as expected. But I have 2 questions:

```
// Save default Account Types
var refTypes = this.housesRef.child(key + "/memberaccounttypes/");
refTypes.push({ name: 'Checking', icon: '0' });
refTypes.push({ name: 'Savings', icon: '0' });
refTypes.push({ name: 'Credit Card', icon: '0' });
refTypes.push({ name: 'Debit Card', icon: '0' });
refTypes.push({ name: 'Investment', icon: '0' });
refTypes.push({ name: 'Brokerage', icon: '0' });
```

1. With this approach, am I doing several trips to Firebase, one for each push?
2. Is there a more efficient, best-practice, way to save the following data all at once?

I'm using Firebase SDK 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to push in this way will indeed result in a roundtrip to Firebase. You can easily verify this by checking the "Web Sockets" pane on network tab of your browser debug tools.

If you'd like to run this as a single update, you can combine them into a multi-location update with:

```
var refTypes = this.housesRef.child(key + "/memberaccounttypes/");
var updates = {};
updates[refTypes.push().key] = { name: 'Checking', icon: '0' };
updates[refTypes.push().key] = { name: 'Savings', icon: '0' };
updates[refTypes.push().key] = { name: 'Credit Card', icon: '0' };
updates[refTypes.push().key] = { name: 'Debit Card', icon: '0' };
updates[refTypes.push().key] = { name: 'Investment', icon: '0' };
updates[refTypes.push().key] = { name: 'Brokerage', icon: '0' };
refTypes.update(updates);
```

Note that this will hardly save any time/bandwidth, since [the Firebase client pipelines requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

Comment: As always, you're the best. Thank you Frank!